# Page from sorted table Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I want to get a page of results using follwing Java code:

```
Page<MyDTO> page = repo.findAllOrderByCreatedDate(new PageRequest(pageNumber,pageSize));
```

In MyDTO I have:

```
@Entity
class MyDTO{

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private LocalDateTime createdDate;

  //getters setters
}
```

What I get is:

```
No parameter available for part createdDate SIMPLE_PROPERTY (1):
[Is, Equals].; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
```

How to combine paging and sortig with Spring Data?

Comment: I think the problem is that Hibernate (prior to version 5) doesn't natively support persisting of LocalDateTime. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616280/java-solutions-for-distributed-transactions-and-or-data-shared-in-cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another constructor of class PageRequest:

```
Page<MyDTO> page = repo.findAll(new PageRequest(pageNumber,pageSize, new Sort("createdDate")));
```